# Do I need to convert OLI bands DN values to reflectance and TIRS bands DN values to radiance?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat-8, reflectance

I know that this a very trivial question. I downloaded some Landsat 8 images from the USGS website that have the following format (I deleted the processing date):

> LC08_L2SP_168057_20200119_20200823_02_T1

I am assuming that this is Level 2 data. I am trying to calculate the NDVI and LST data. The pixel values of all the bands are in 16 bits. My question is do I need to convert OLI bands DN values to reflectance and TIRS bands DN values to radiance? I thought that Level 2 data are already Top of atmosphere (i.e, reflectance and surface temperature). I tried to read related threads and the user manual, but couldn`t make sense of it.